# Java Spring WS org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapEnvelopeException: Could not access envelope

Tags: java, spring

I'am experencing a strange behaviour of a spring ws in different environments. Following works fine with Soap UI on a local tomcat 7.0.29, but does return below mentioned error.

servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholder"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>classpath:ws.properties</value>
    </property>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_FALLBACK" />
    <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
</bean>


<bean
    class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WsdlDefinitionHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="transformLocations" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageFactory">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="payloadMapping"
    class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref local="validatingInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="validatingInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor"
    autowire="byName">
    <property name="schema" value="/xsd/schema.xsd" />
    <property name="validateRequest" value="true" />
    <property name="validateResponse" value="true" />
</bean>



<bean
    class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver" />





<bean id="defaultHandlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />

<bean id="baseWsdlDefinition" abstract="true"
    class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
    <property name="requestSuffix" value="Request" />
    <property name="responseSuffix" value="Response" />
</bean>

<bean id="sampleJaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.db.vhs.ws.jaxb.PlacementRequest</value>
            <value>com.db.vhs.ws.jaxb.PlacementResponse</value>...
```

scheam.xsd:

```
<xs:annotation>

    <xs:appinfo>

        <jaxb:globalBindings>

            <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime"
                printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime" />

        </jaxb:globalBindings>

    </xs:appinfo>

</xs:annotation>




<!-- getClusterRequest -->

<xs:element name="getClusterRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="getClusterResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long" />
            <xs:element name="Vcenter" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="NAME" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="MOREF" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="OVERALLSTATUS" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="COLLECTIONDATE" type="xs:dateTime" />
            <xs:element name="DPMENABLED" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="DRSENABLED" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="HAENABLED" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="NUMCPUCORES" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="NUMHOSTS" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="TOTALCPU" type="xs:long" />
            <xs:element name="TOTALMEMORY" type="xs:long" />
            <xs:element name="VDatacenterID" type="xs:long" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>


<xs:element name="placementRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="request_header" type="header" />
            <xs:element name="request_body" type="requestBody" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>




<xs:complexType name="header">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="request_id" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="uuid" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="request_type">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="1" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>



<xs:complexType name="requestBody">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="cluster_request" type="clusterRequest" />
            <xs:element name="region_request" type="regionRequest" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>



<xs:complexType name="clusterRequest">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="cluster" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="regionRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="region" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="OS" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="clusterProductType">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:list itemType="xs:string" />
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="class">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="3" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="class_type">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="2" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="subnet" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>





<xs:element name="placementResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="response_header" type="header" />
            <xs:element name="response_body" type="responseBody" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>





<xs:complexType name="responseBody">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="class">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="3" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="capacity">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="cluster">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="cluster_name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                <xs:element name="v_center" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xs:element name="storage" type="storage"></xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xs:element name="host" type="host"></xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="class_type" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                <xs:element name="timestamp" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>




<!-- complex types for response ngp -->


<xs:complexType name="storage">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="data_store_name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="total_storage" type="xs:long" />
        <xs:element name="allocated_storage" type="xs:long" />
        <xs:element name="storage_class" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:complexType name="host">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="host_name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="port_group_name" type="portgroup" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="physical_cpus" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element name="allocated_cpus" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element name="available_cpu_size" type="xs:long" />
        <xs:element name="average_cpu_usage" type="xs:double" />
        <xs:element name="max_cpu_usage" type="xs:double" />
        <xs:element name="physical_memory" type="xs:long" />
        <xs:element name="allocated_memory" type="xs:long" />
        <xs:element name="average_memory_usage" type="xs:double" />
        <xs:element name="max_memory_usage" type="xs:double" />
        <xs:element name="number_of_vms" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="portgroup">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="subnet" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The first method works in both environments, the second (placementRequest) returns:

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.29 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapEnvelopeException: Could not access envelope: Unable to create envelope from given source: ; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source: </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapEnvelopeException: Could not access envelope: Unable to create envelope from given source: ; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source: </u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error (Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapEnvelopeException: Could not access envelope: Unable to create envelope from given source: ; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source: ) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapEnvelopeException: Could not access envelope: Unable to create envelope from given source: ; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source:
```

org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:583)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

**root cause**

```
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapEnvelopeException: Could not access envelope: Unable to create envelope from given source: ; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source:
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getEnvelope(SaajSoapMessage.java:107)
org.springframework.ws.soap.AbstractSoapMessage.getSoapBody(AbstractSoapMessage.java:36)
org.springframework.ws.soap.AbstractSoapMessage.getPayloadSource(AbstractSoapMessage.java:46)
org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.getLookupKeyForMessage(PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.java:57)
org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.AbstractMethodEndpointMapping.getEndpointInternal(AbstractMethodEndpointMapping.java:56)
org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.AbstractEndpointMapping.getEndpoint(AbstractEndpointMapping.java:83)
org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.getEndpoint(MessageDispatcher.java:248)
org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:201)
org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:168)
org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:57)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

**root cause**

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source:
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:114)
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:70)
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:122)
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.Saaj13Implementation.getEnvelope(Saaj13Implementation.java:169)
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getEnvelope(SaajSoapMessage.java:103)
org.springframework.ws.soap.AbstractSoapMessage.getSoapBody(AbstractSoapMessage.java:36)
org.springframework.ws.soap.AbstractSoapMessage.getPayloadSource(AbstractSoapMessage.java:46)
org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.getLookupKeyForMessage(PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.java:57)
org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.AbstractMethodEndpointMapping.getEndpointInternal(AbstractMethodEndpointMapping.java:56)
org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.AbstractEndpointMapping.getEndpoint(AbstractEndpointMapping.java:83)
org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.getEndpoint(MessageDispatcher.java:248)
org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:201)
org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:168)
org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:57)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

**root cause**

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:719)
com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:313)
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.transform(EfficientStreamingTransformer.java:393)
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:102)
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:70)
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:122)
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.Saaj13Implementation.getEnvelope(Saaj13Implementation.java:169)
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getEnvelope(SaajSoapMessage.java:103)
org.springframework.ws.soap.AbstractSoapMessage.getSoapBody(AbstractSoapMessage.java:36)
org.springframework.ws.soap.AbstractSoapMessage.getPayloadSource(AbstractSoapMessage.java:46)
org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.getLookupKeyForMessage(PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.java:57)
org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.AbstractMethodEndpointMapping.getEndpointInternal(AbstractMethodEndpointMapping.java:56)
org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.AbstractEndpointMapping.getEndpoint(AbstractEndpointMapping.java:83)
org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.getEndpoint(MessageDispatcher.java:248)
org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:201)
org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:168)
org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:57)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

**root cause**

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1231)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:636)
com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:707)
com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:313)
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.transform(EfficientStreamingTransformer.java:393)
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:102)
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:70)
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:122)
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.Saaj13Implementation.getEnvelope(Saaj13Implementation.java:169)
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getEnvelope(SaajSoapMessage.java:103)
org.springframework.ws.soap.AbstractSoapMessage.getSoapBody(AbstractSoapMessage.java:36)
org.springframework.ws.soap.AbstractSoapMessage.getPayloadSource(AbstractSoapMessage.java:46)
org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.getLookupKeyForMessage(PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.java:57)
org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.AbstractMethodEndpointMapping.getEndpointInternal(AbstractMethodEndpointMapping.java:56)
org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.AbstractEndpointMapping.getEndpoint(AbstractEndpointMapping.java:83)
org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.getEndpoint(MessageDispatcher.java:248)
org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:201)
org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:168)
org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:57)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

**note** The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.29 logs.

#### Apache Tomcat/7.0.29

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.29</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core-tiger</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
        <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cloudbees.thirdparty</groupId>
        <artifactId>vijava</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I read that it could be that the web server overrides the maven dependencies? Or do you have any suggestions how to solve this? Greatly appreciated if someone can help!!!

Comment: Noone has come over this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error as you. I've found the solution here: http://mmmsoftware.blogspot.com.es/2009/06/xml-namespace-error-with-spring-ws.html

Basically you have to use upper versions of **xalan** and **xercesimpl**. My pom's dependencies look like this:

```
<project ...>
 ...
<dependencies>

             ...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>maven-cobertura-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>maven-plugins</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>maven-findbugs-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>maven-plugins</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

             ...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
 ...
</project>
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Glad to see my blog came in handy :P

Answer (score 3):

I've just managed the same problem.

In my situation the problem was in old spring-ws version being used with HTTPS.

Upgrading to the latest (2.1.3) helped.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks Val :)

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem

i created xml file that write a envelope soup in it.and run it by curl like this:

curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction:urn:LoginRequest" --data @loginRequest.xml http://.....:8080/.../LoginRequest.asmx

then it return upper exception .

in my case ,the problem was extra line in loginRequest.xml

i just remove extra line
,it fixed
:)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  This is a suggestion posted as an answer. Please take a look at [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)