# Spring WS 2.0.0 and Spring Integration 2.0.1. Exception Could not access envelope: Unable to create envelope from given source:

Tags: java, xml, spring, web-services, soap

SOLUTION FOR THE PROBLEM DESCRIBED BELOW IS AT
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17513891/1168976

I have web service based Spring WS 2.0.0 and Spring Integration 2.0.1 to process the SOAP body received by the web service. It configured for **HTTPS**.
Running on JDK 1.6.0_23 and TOMCAT 6

Web Service runs fine most of the time, but once in a while it will fail to process the request from client with following exception: (if this failed request through client is processed using SOAP UI it works fine)

```
Could not complete request
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapEnvelopeException: Could not access envelope: Unable to create envelope from given source: ; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source: 
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getSaajVersion(SaajSoapMessage.java:260)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getImplementation(SaajSoapMessage.java:342)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.<init>(SaajSoapMessage.java:117)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:184)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:58)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:90)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:86)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source: 
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:114)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:122)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.support.SaajUtils.getSaajVersion(SaajUtils.java:155)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getSaajVersion(SaajSoapMessage.java:257)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:502)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.transform(EfficientStreamingTransformer.java:393)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:102)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1231)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:485)
    ... 31 more
```

POM XML Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.spring-library</artifactId>
            <type>libd</type>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <classifier>all</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-ws</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-stream</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opensymphony.quartz</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.org.quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
          <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Looks like you response is not well-formed:`The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.`.

Comment: No the same xml works using SOAP UI. So markup seems to be correct.

Comment: I suggest you to add some `Filter` for the `MessageDispatcherServlet` to see how the request looks. Or you can use any network sniffer application to trace the traffic. Since you say that your service works well, but sometimes it fails with that issue, it looks like the client of your service sometimes sends the bad request.