# Unable to create envelope from given source because the root element is not named Envelope

Tags: java, soap, remedy

I have a SOAP request that I've tested in SoapUI. I successfully get the desired response.

The problem in my code occurs when I'm testing whether or not the response was successful at `if (isSuccessResponse(soapResponse)) {` below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

 // Establish SOAP connection
 SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
 SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

 // Generate SOAP request
 SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), namespaceURI);

 // Test to see if SOAP response is available
 System.out.print("SOAP Response:");
 System.out.println();
 soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);

 // Close connection
 soapConnection.close();

 if (isSuccessResponse(soapResponse)) {
  System.out.println("Success!");
 } else {
  System.out.println("Fault!");
 }

}
```

**Success?**

```
private static boolean isSuccessResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {
 NodeList responseNodes = soapResponse.getSOAPBody().getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "HelpDesk_QueryList_Service");

 if (responseNodes.getLength() == 1)
  return true;
 else
  return false;
}
```

**Request:**
This code does in fact print out the correct request as it is identical to the working request in SoapUI. So why can't I get the related relevant information from the actual response? The printed response is the blank default response with all the of requisite headers but none of the desired information from my request:

```
private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
 MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();

 // Create SOAP Message
 SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

 // Add request envelope, headers, and nodes from SOAP request 
 SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

 // I used ? here for privacy reasons
 String xmlns = "?";
 String username = "?";
 String password = "?";
 String qualification = "'?";

 SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
 envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("urn", xmlns);

 SOAPHeader soapHeader = envelope.getHeader();
 SOAPElement authInfoElem = soapHeader.addChildElement("AuthenticationInfo", "urn");
 createElementAndSetText(authInfoElem, "userName", username);
 createElementAndSetText(authInfoElem, "password", password);

 SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
 SOAPElement bodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("HelpDesk_QueryList_Service", "urn");
 createElementAndSetText(bodyElem, "Qualification", qualification);

 MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
 headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", xmlns + "/HelpDesk_QueryList_Service");

 // Save request
 soapMessage.saveChanges();

 // Print the request message
 System.out.print("SOAP Request:");
 System.out.println();
 soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
 System.out.println();
 System.out.println();

 return soapMessage;
}
```

**Error:** I get the following error but I'm not sure why.

```
Lis 07, 2016 6:10:34 ODP. com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl lookForEnvelope
SEVERE: SAAJ0514: Unable to create envelope from given source because the root element is not named Envelope
Lis 07, 2016 6:10:34 ODP. com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory createEnvelope
SEVERE: SAAJ0511: Unable to create envelope from given source
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source: 
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:117)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:69)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getSOAPBody(MessageImpl.java:1351)
    at com.xxxx.automation.remedy.RemedySOAPService.isSuccessResponse(RemedySOAPService.java:135)
    at com.xxxx.automation.remedy.RemedySOAPService.main(RemedySOAPService.java:52)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source because the root element is not named "Envelope"
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.lookForEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:154)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:121)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:110)
    ... 5 more

CAUSE:

com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source because the root element is not named "Envelope"
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.lookForEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:154)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:121)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:69)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getSOAPBody(MessageImpl.java:1351)
    at com.xxxx.automation.remedy.RemedySOAPService.isSuccessResponse(RemedySOAPService.java:135)
    at com.xxxx.automation.remedy.RemedySOAPService.main(RemedySOAPService.java

:52)
```

**SOAP Response:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns0:HelpDesk_QueryList_ServiceResponse xmlns:ns0="urn:XX:XXXX:HPD_IncidentInterface_WS">
         <ns0:getListValues>
            <ns0:Assigned_Group>XXXX</ns0:Assigned_Group>
            <ns0:Assigned_Group_Shift_Name/>
            <ns0:Assigned_Support_Company>XXXX</ns0:Assigned_Support_Company>
            <ns0:Assigned_Support_Organization>XXXX</ns0:Assigned_Support_Organization>
            <ns0:Assignee/>
            <ns0:Categorization_Tier_1/>
            <ns0:Categorization_Tier_2/>
            <ns0:Categorization_Tier_3/>
            <ns0:City/>
            <ns0:Closure_Manufacturer/>
            <ns0:Closure_Product_Category_Tier1>XXXX</ns0:Closure_Product_Category_Tier1>
            <ns0:Closure_Product_Category_Tier2>XXXX</ns0:Closure_Product_Category_Tier2>
            <ns0:Closure_Product_Category_Tier3/>
            <ns0:Closure_Product_Model_Version/>
            <ns0:Closure_Product_Name/>
            <ns0:Company>XXXX</ns0:Company>
            <ns0:Contact_Company>XXXX</ns0:Contact_Company>
            <ns0:Contact_Sensitivity>Standard</ns0:Contact_Sensitivity>
            <ns0:Country/>
            <ns0:Department>XXXX</ns0:Department>
            <ns0:Summary>XXXX</ns0:Summary>
            <ns0:Notes/>
            <ns0:First_Name>XXXX</ns0:First_Name>
            <ns0:Impact>4-Minor/Localized</ns0:Impact>
            <ns0:Incident_Number>XXXX</ns0:Incident_Number>
            <ns0:Internet_E-mail>XXXX</ns0:Internet_E-mail>
            <ns0:Last_Name>XXXX</ns0:Last_Name>
            <ns0:Manufacturer/>
            <ns0:Organization>XXXX</ns0:Organization>
            <ns0:Phone_Number>XXXX</ns0:Phone_Number>
            <ns0:Priority>Low</ns0:Priority>
            <ns0:Priority_Weight>0</ns0:Priority_Weight>
            <ns0:Product_Categorization_Tier_1>XXXX</ns0:Product_Categorization_Tier_1>
            <ns0:Product_Categorization_Tier_2>XXXX</ns0:Product_Categorization_Tier_2>
            <ns0:Product_Categorization_Tier_3/>
            <ns0:Product_Model_Version/>
            <ns0:Product_Name/>
            <ns0:Region/>
            <ns0:Reported_Source xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ns0:Resolution/>
            <ns0:Resolution_Category/>
            <ns0:Resolution_Category_Tier_2/>
            <ns0:Resolution_Category_Tier_3/>
            <ns0:Service_Type>User Service Restoration</ns0:Service_Type>
            <ns0:Site>XXXX</ns0:Site>
            <ns0:Site_Group>XXXX</ns0:Site_Group>
            <ns0:Status>Cancelled</ns0:Status>
            <ns0:Status_Reason xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ns0:Urgency>4-Low</ns0:Urgency>
            <ns0:VIP>No</ns0:VIP>
            <ns0:ServiceCI/>
            <ns0:ServiceCI_ReconID/>
            <ns0:HPD_CI/>
            <ns0:HPD_CI_ReconID/>
            <ns0:HPD_CI_FormName/>
            <ns0:z1D_CI_FormName/>
            <ns0:Vendor_Ticket_Number xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ns0:Corporate_ID>XXXX</ns0:Corporate_ID>
            <ns0:Submitter>XXXX</ns0:Submitter>
            <ns0:Pending_Date xsi:nil="true"/>
         </ns0:getListValues>
      </ns0:HelpDesk_QueryList_ServiceResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: From my reading: The stack is not in the forging of the request, but in the processing of the response. Is the response valid SOAP ?

Comment: I really think the problem is in here: ``private static boolean isSuccessResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {`` but I'm not sure what's going wrong just yet.

Comment: I've included a sample successful response above. For one, the name of my response was wrong, so I'll change HelpDesk_QueryList_Service to HelpDesk_QueryList_ServiceResponse...

Answer (score 2):

First, it seems that your error occurs while the SAAJ framework processes the response. So I would not dig on the creation of the request, that I would assume is fine, particularly since you make the case that it is the same that the SoapUI forged one. You could also check HTTP headers to make extra sure of that.

The important part of the stack trace is :

```
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:128)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getSOAPBody(MessageImpl.java:1351)
```

Which tells us that the SOAP framework could not process the *response envelope*. Assuming the response is indeed valid, this looks suspiscious.

Looking at your code, what I suspect this is a misuse of the SAAJ API :

```
// Close connection
soapConnection.close();

if (isSuccessResponse(soapResponse)) {
  System.out.println("Success!");
} else {
  System.out.println("Fault!");
}
```

You close the connection before actually using the message. If the SAAJ implemetation is lazy (which I guess it is, it would make sense), the message is not immediatly parsed from the network Socket. By closing the connection *before* using the response message, you actually shut the socket before it has been read, and the implementation consequently can not read the message.

I would suggest delaying the closing of the connection to *after* you used the response object.

The same argument can be made of this part of the code :

```
 System.out.print("SOAP Response:");
 System.out.println();
 soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);

 // Close connection
 soapConnection.close();
```

By dumping the response to the console, you actually make the framework consume the socket (read the HTTP response). Once you, later, ask the framework to parse the response stream as an envelope, if it has not cached the contents of the stream, then this operation fails : there are no more bytes to parse.

So in a nutshell : do not "touch" the connection or the repsonse object before the framework has a chance to actually parse the result. This is not obvious from a API design standpoint, but it's an understandable behavior.

Some other leads : 
Others on stackoverflow have reported that their old versions of Xerces/Xalan were the culprit (those are XML parsers, the JDK has its own version of Xerces built in), so you might want to check this too : 
[Java Spring WS org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapEnvelopeException: Could not access envelope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467186/java-spring-ws-org-springframework-ws-soap-saaj-saajsoapenvelopeexception-could/13156775#13156775)
http://mmmsoftware.blogspot.fr/2009/06/xml-namespace-error-with-spring-ws.html

Comment: Moving ``soapConnection.close();`` below or after checking ``isSuccessResponse(soapResponse)`` doesn't seem to work. Hmm...

Comment: I'll edit. THe next suspect is the response.writeTo(System.out), which consumes the stream !

Comment: Good points and I'll incorporate the changes into my design but it doesn't seem to prevent SAAJ errors. After debugging, the problem is definitely here: ``NodeList responseNodes = soapResponse.getSOAPBody().getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "HelpDesk_QueryList_ServiceResponse");``

Comment: After a quick look around, I found other possibilities, but i'm running out of options here. I would advise to grep the source and debug internally if this still does not work.